# How can I enqueue script based on template part?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to be able to load scripts and stylesheets in the head and foot based on wordpress get template part

#### I have on in my front-page.php the following code:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Home Page
*/

get_header();

$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'home_page','posts_per_page'=>1, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'DESC') ); 
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

if( get_field('home_page_template_type') == 'Bookcase') {

    get_template_part( 'bookcase' ); 

}elseif (get_field('home_page_template_type') == 'Bookers') {

    get_template_part('bookers' ); 

}

endwhile;

get_footer();
```

#### Now in my functions php I want to do this

```
// Register Script
if (!function_exists('theme_scripts')) {
    function villarosa_theme_scripts() {
        global $wp_scripts;

        if ('bookcase.php') {
            // Load our main stylesheet.
            wp_deregister_style( 'bookcase-styles' );
            wp_register_style( 'bookcase-styles',trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookcase/css/style.css', false, '1.0' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'bookcase-styles' );

            // jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) 
            wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
            wp_register_script( 'jquery', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookcase/js/jquery.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

            wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-migrate' );
            wp_register_script( 'jquery-migrate', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookcase/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-migrate' );

            wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-easing' );
            wp_register_script( 'jquery-easing', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookcase/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-easing' );

            wp_deregister_script( 'script' );
            wp_register_script( 'script', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookcase/js/script.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'script' );

            wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-equalheights' );
            wp_register_script( 'jquery-equalheights', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookcase/js/jquery.equalheights.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-equalheights' );

            wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-ui-totop' );
            wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-totop', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookcase/js/jquery.ui.totop.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-totop' );

            wp_deregister_script( 'superfish' );
            wp_register_script( 'superfish', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookcase/js/superfish.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'superfish' );

            wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-mobilemenu' );
            wp_register_script( 'jquery-mobilemenu', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookcase/js/jquery.mobilemenu.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-mobilemenu' );

            wp_deregister_script( 'sForm' );
            wp_register_script( 'sForm', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookcase/js/sForm.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'sForm' );

        } else if ('bookers.php') {
            // Load our main stylesheet.
            wp_deregister_style( 'bookers-styles' );
            wp_register_style( 'bookers-styles',trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookers/css/style.css', false, '1.0' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'bookers-styles' );

            wp_deregister_style( 'stuck' );
            wp_register_style( 'stuck',trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookers/css/stuck.css', false, '1.0' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'stuck' );

            // jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) 
            wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
            wp_register_script( 'jquery', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookers/js/jquery.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

            wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-migrate' );
            wp_register_script( 'jquery-migrate', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookers/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-migrate' );

            wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-easing' );
            wp_register_script( 'jquery-easing', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookers/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-easing' );

            wp_deregister_script( 'script' );
            wp_register_script( 'script', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookers/js/script.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'script' );

            wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-equalheights' );
            wp_register_script( 'jquery-equalheights', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookers/js/jquery.equalheights.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-equalheights' );

            wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-ui-totop' );
            wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui-totop', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookers/js/jquery.ui.totop.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-totop' );

            wp_deregister_script( 'superfish' );
            wp_register_script( 'superfish', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookers/js/superfish.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'superfish' );

            wp_deregister_script( 'tmStickUp' );
            wp_register_script( 'tmStickUp', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookers/js/tmStickUp.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'tmStickUp' );

            wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-mobilemenu' );
            wp_register_script( 'jquery-mobilemenu', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'bookers/js/jquery.mobilemenu.js', false, '1.0', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-mobilemenu' );
        }
    }
}
```

However the scripts are loading for my first condition but for else if they are not? Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if tests for something tangible if you pass it a string or variable. e.g. `if($var)` will equate to `if($var != null)` so your function is not progressing beyond `if ('bookcase.php')` as it is always true (you are not testing if this file exists, you are testing whether its not null)

Probably what you want is:

```
 function villarosa_theme_scripts($type) {
    if($type==='bookcase'):
       // enqueue scripts
    elseif($type==='bookers':
       // enqueue scripts
    endif;
 }
```

and you can call it on your template directly *place this code before your header......

```
if( get_field('home_page_template_type') == 'Bookcase') {

        get_template_part( 'bookcase' ); 
        villarosa_theme_scripts('bookcase');

}elseif (get_field('home_page_template_type') == 'Bookers') {

        get_template_part('bookers' ); 
        villarosa_theme_scripts('bookers');

}
get_header();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are calling villarosa_theme_scripts, but in any case:

```
if ('bookcase.php')
```

will always evaluate to true. You need to be testing some variable (I assume it's a WordPress template name), like:

```
if ($template == 'bookcase.php')
```